# Water on the left side of the trunk on a VW Golf mk4

Tags: golf, tail-lights, water-leak, trunk

I've found water on the left side of the trunk on my Golf mk4 and I'm suspecting that it's coming from the tail lights that there are not longer tightly sealed.

- How can I check that? I'm thinking on just pour water over the trunk and check… but right now we have -4ºC and we are heading to -15ºC in the following days, so I don't think this is a good idea.
- Is there a possibility that it's another source? Like a hole underneath? I've been checking and I haven't seen anything.
- If they are finally the lights. How difficult could be to reseal the lights? I guess I need to take the lights, at lest the left one, and try to reseal with something. What something?

### Background and additional info

I live in Finland, and this winter has been horrible. All the winter temperatures have been dancing around zero.

On November, I have to take the car to the shop because there was a lot of water on the trunk and washer pump just stopped working. So they told me that they changed the pump and repaired the hose that connects to the pump.

Now, I just found water again. In the beginning I thought that it was just snow and humidity and after dry pretty well the area with a small warmer I found water again after a rainy day. The waster was just water, not washer liquid like the previous time.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely the tail light seal or the trunk seal.  VW's are notorious for taking on water.  You say the tail lights are no longer tightly sealed?  That's probably the culprit.  I think the only way to properly fix that would be to buy new seals.

Unfortunately the only way to really find the leak is to get in the trunk and have someone spray the car with a hose.  You may have to wait until spring for that.  If there is a lot of water, you can pop out the drain plugs in the trunk and at least there won't be a puddle.  When the weather breaks you can determine the entry point.

Comment: where are those drain plugs? Are several around of just one?

Comment: Should be a few in the trunk area. Definitely in the spare tire well if your car has one.  They are about the size of a milk bottle top.  Made of rubber and they just push or pry out.

Comment: I'm thinking that the problem are the drain plugs not being sealed correctly.